# How to include external php variable outside of WHMCS into whmcs?

Tags: javascript, php, templates, whmcs

What I am trying to do is inject the username from the website into WHMCS. The website is NOT integrated with WHMCS. WHMCS is installed in a subdirectory of my website.

The website directory structure looks like this:

```
mywebsite.com
  whmcs_directory
```

mywebsite.com is a website with members. It is not wordpress, it is a custom php site.

The whmcs directory is installed as a subdirectory of my website (in a folder inside the website root).

I created a custom field in WHMCS called "username".

Then I wrote javascript to inject and fill the username field. I got that part working fine in `viewcart.php`. What I mean by "working fine", is that I can define any value like "myvalue" manually and include it using javascript:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
       $('#customfield1').val('myvalue')
    })
</script>
```

I included that javascript in viewcart.php. It injects `myvalue` into the input field. However, I can't put any real php in there, and obviously everyone's username is not "myvalue". I need to fetch a dynamic php variable from outside whmcs.

===========================================================

Now, I was able to fetch my own code just fine using a raw php file called `test.php`. I could easily inject the username from the site into an input field in a raw php file.

I did it by simply including the header, the "get the user id" code below, writing some brief php to call it, and then injecting via javascript into the input field. Super easy.

```
<?php 

  //get the header
  require_once('theheader.php');

  // get the user id
  $theuser = GetTheUser::loadUser($Auth->id);

  // make variable and stuff
  $username    = $theuser->username;
  echo isset($username) ? validation::safeOutputToScreen($username) : ''; 
?>

<!-- convert to js variable -->
var username = <?php echo json_encode($username); ?>;

<!-- inject username into username input -->
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
       $('#inputfield1').val(username)
    })
</script>
```

That works in my raw php page `test.php` and injects the logged in user in my main site into the input field in `test.php` page.

However, when I try to include the `GetTheUser` code (wrapped in smarty `{php}{/php}`) into `viewcart.tpl` unfortunately it results in a php error, `Fatal error: Class 'GetTheUser' not found in /home/mysite.com/whmcs/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/SmartyBC.class.php(464) : eval()'d code on line 2`.

So I just need to somehow get this username and inject it into the cart page in whmcs.

I tried to add php code into `cart.php` but it results in whmcs telling me `the file is corrupted` php error page. So it's not possible to put php into cart.php in whmcs unfortunately.

---

Please tell me how I can get my outside php variable from mysite.com which is my custom php site and insert into the cart page on my whmcs mysite.com/whmcs/cart.php

Answer (score 1):

In WHMCS you don't edit core php files, you edit template files, found in templates folder.
To choose templates, use General Settings, you select which Template to use for the client area in General tab, and which template to use for Cart in Ordering tab.

You can get username as following:

**In the website:**

`mywebsite.com/test.php`

Add link with Get variable containing the username:

`<a href="mywhmcs/cart.php?act=view&un=someuser"></a>`

Note: you can use a form to send post request instead.

**In WHMCS**

Create the following file: `includes/hooks/website.php`

Add this code to it:

```
<?php
add_hook('ClientAreaPageCart', 1, function($vars) {
    if (isset($_GET['un'])) {
        $username = filter_var($_GET['un'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return array('username' => $username);
    }

});
```

This is a hook to execute when Cart page is visited.

**In order form template**

(Located at templates/orderforms/standard_cart if you didn't change default)

Edit the file related to the service you're targeting, for example, the template file for registering a domain name is:
`adddomain.tpl`

You can add variable we prepared in the hook above as following:

`<input type="hidden" name="username" value="{$username}" />`